# Gáfico atualiza automático com últimos 12 dados

Tags: microsoft-excel, gráfico

Então pessoal, já estou horas tentando e nada.

Quero que o gráfico atualize automático com os últimos 12 dados colocados.

Estou tentando colocar a seguinte fórmula no GERENCIADOR DE NOME:

```
=DESLOC(Plan1!$F$6:$XF$6;CONT.VALORES(Plan1!$F$6:$XF$6)-12;0)
```

E na SELEÇÃO DE DADOS para o gráfico essa fórmula:

```
=Plan1!porcentagem
```

Mas acontece que essa fórmula acontece quando o gráfico está com os VALORES APENAS NA MESMA COLUNA. Porém nessa tabela que estou utilizando os DADOS ESTÃO TODOS NA MESMA LINHA.

Já alterei a fórmula DESLOC várias vezes e nada, aparece um gráfico totalmente fora do comum. Segue foto da tabela que utilizo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite!

Para explicar melhor o que sua fórmula está fazendo atualmente, segue abaixo:
Está deslocando sempre (N - 12) linhas, onde N = Qtd. de Valores no intervalo

[image: Está deslocando sempre N-12 linhas]

Se puder mandar mais detalhes, talvez possa ajudar.

Comment: @danieltakeshi Entendo que isso é uma resposta ou um comentário longo, mas não vejo como algo que deveria estar na pergunta.

Comment: é para deslocar à direita, porém como faço isso? ele desloca na horizontal e não na vertical.

Comment: @EduardoS É só trocar o deslocamento de linhas para coluna. Na fórmula você inverte fica assim: =DESLOC(referencia;0 linhas; N colunas).

Comment: @EduardoS Se a resposta solucionou o seu problema, favor ler [como aceitar uma resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/75104)

Comment: Não funcionou, tentei trocar colocando 0 linhas

Comment: Mas muito obrigado!